# Broken Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt

I had the ubuntu 12.10 up and running. But somehow I managed to mess it all up.
Now, I do not get the login screen. It keeps on getting a black screen and cursor blink at something " Jupiter healthcheck ".

Pressing random keys, I could get to the terminal.

I tried this:

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Output was :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: nautilus but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: nautilus-sendto but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: brasero but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: transmission-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I get go ahead ?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f` & `sudo apt-get upgrade`. then use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and 
`sudo apt-get install unity`

Comment: Did everything you said. But no success. Unity is installed already. And the reinstall command gives the same output as above.

Comment: Please post the output of `dpkg --get-selection | grep hold`.  Also, please try to install one of the packages that is complaining, like `nautilus`.  You should get more informative error messages.  If you get the same thing again, keep trying on the new package until you get something with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some repos disabled. First of all, let's reenable them with this command:

```
 sudo software-properties-gtk -e universe multiverse restricted
```

After that, install the `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

**NOTE**

If you don't have `software-properties-gtk` installed, then install it with:
`sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk`
command.

Comment: I followed everything you said. But the response to installing ubuntu-desktop is the same as above.

Comment: Ok, how about `sudo apt-get install unity`?

Comment: Already did that. It was installed alright.